# Comparing Two Groups with Binary Indicator Variable Showing Each Study Arm, Selecting Only Group with Indicator for Analysis

Tags: r, trial, summarization

I have a dataset:

```
Count   Group    Time
2       1        123123
1       1         1231231 
45      1          145124
25      2          132451
1       2           434114
52      2            1313
```

I want to run an analysis in each arm ie. group=1 and group=2.
So I need to analyze all count variables for only group=1 and then for only group=2.

Comment: what analysis do you want? what is your output?

Comment: goodfit(x, type = c("poisson", "binomial", "nbinomial"),
  method = c("ML", "MinChisq"), par = NULL)

Comment: x 
either a vector of counts, a 1-way table of frequencies of counts or a data frame or matrix with frequencies in the first column and the corresponding counts in the second column.

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel So I need x for each count in the study... for when group =1 and when group =2 Time is unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Count <- c(2, 1, 45, 25, 1, 52)
Group <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
Time  <- c(123123, 1231231, 145124, 132451, 434114, 1313)
df    <- as.data.frame(cbind(Count, Group, Time))

aggregate(c(df$Count), list(df$Group), sum)
aggregate(c(df$Count), list(df$Group), mean)
aggregate(c(df$Time), list(df$Group), sum)
aggregate(c(df$Time), list(df$Group), mean)

glm(Count ~ Time, subset = Group, data = df)
```